# QT CLI Option Add more value names

Tags: qt, command-line-interface

I am improving a QT CLI and I would like to simplify some options, for example to add a username with password, right now it is necessary to pass --passwod.

```
-a, --add <username>   Adds a new user.

--password <password>  Password
```

I would like to have something like this, but it seems QT only allows one value name.

```
-a, --add <username> <password>  Adds a new user.
```

Is there a way I can implement this with QT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCommandLineParser expects one value for each option. You can use positional argument for password in your case.